# Is $\sin\left[2\alpha\right]\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\ge0$ a valid restriction on the angles of the principal stresses in 2D elasticity?

Tags: conventions, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, textbook-erratum

This question pertains to [Elasticity: Tensor, Dyadic, and Engineering Approaches](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486669580.html) By: Pei Chi Chou, Nicholas J. Pagano, Section 1.4.

The objective under discussion is to find the directions of stationary normal stress. The following transformation equations have been established:

$$\sigma^{\overline{x}}=\sigma^{x}\cos^{2}\left[\alpha\right]+\sigma^{y}\sin^{2}\left[\alpha\right]+2\tau^{x}{}_{y}\cos\left[\alpha\right]\sin\left[\alpha\right],\tag{1.5}$$

$$\sigma^{\overline{y}}=\sigma^{x}\sin^{2}\left[\alpha\right]+\sigma^{y}\cos^{2}\left[\alpha\right]-2\tau^{x}{}_{y}\cos\left[\alpha\right]\sin\left[\alpha\right].\tag{1.7}$$

Using the trigonometric identities

$$\sin\left[2\alpha\right]=2\cos\left[\alpha\right]\sin\left[\alpha\right],\tag{1.8a}$$

$$\sin^{2}\left[\alpha\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\right),\tag{1.8b}$$

$$\cos^{2}\left[\alpha\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\right),\tag{1.8c}$$

these become

$$\sigma^{\overline{x}}=\frac{\sigma^{x}+\sigma^{y}}{2}+\left(\frac{\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}}{2}\cos\left[2\alpha\right]+\tau^{x}{}_{y}\sin\left[2\alpha\right]\right),\tag{1.9a}$$

$$\sigma^{\overline{y}}=\frac{\sigma^{x}+\sigma^{y}}{2}-\left(\frac{\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}}{2}\cos\left[2\alpha\right]+\tau^{x}{}_{y}\sin\left[2\alpha\right]\right).\tag{1.9b}$$

We set the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ of either of these equations ($\sigma^{\overline{x}}$ in this case) equal to zero

$$\left(\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}\right)\sin\left[2\alpha\right]=2\tau^{x}{}_{y}\cos\left[2\alpha\right],\tag{1.11}$$
and find the two roots $\left\{ 2\alpha_{1},2\alpha_{2}\right\}$  of the resulting trigonometric expression 
$$\tan\left[2\alpha\right]=\frac{2\tau^{x}{}_{y}}{\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}}.\tag{1.12}$$

It follows that $2\alpha_{2}=2\alpha_{1}\pm\pi;$ thus $\alpha_{2}=\alpha_{1}\pm\frac{\pi}{2}.$ The sine and cosine of $2\alpha$ are

$$\sin\left[2\alpha\right]=\pm\frac{2\tau^{x}{}_{y}}{\sqrt{4\left(\tau^{x}{}_{y}\right)^{2}+\left(\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}\right)^{2}}},\tag{1.12a}$$

$$\cos\left[2\alpha\right]=\pm\frac{\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}}{\sqrt{4\left(\tau^{x}{}_{y}\right)^{2}+\left(\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}\right)^{2}}}.\tag{1.12b}$$

In the first sentence of page 10, **the book claims that $\sin\left[2\alpha\right]$ and $\cos\left[2\alpha\right]$ are either both positive or both negative.** That would restrict $\alpha$ to $0\le\alpha\le\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}\le\alpha\le\frac{3\pi}{4}$. More significantly, it would require $\tau^{x}{}_{y}$ and $\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}$ to have the same arithmetic sign. I see no justification for either of those restrictions. **Is the claim that $\sin\left[2\alpha\right]\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\ge0$ valid?**

The assertion that arithmetic signs of $\sin\left[2\alpha\right]$ and $\cos\left[2\alpha\right]$ must match appears to contradict the discussion in the final paragraph on page 10 in which the case of

$$\frac{\pi}{2}<2\alpha\iff2\tau^{x}{}_{y}>0\wedge\left(\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}\right)<0$$

is considered. That clearly makes the signs of eq 1.12a and eq 1.12b different.

It *might* be the case that any system can be fully characterized by considering a range of angles which conforms to $\sin\left[2\alpha\right]\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\ge0$ , but that is not the claim made by the authors.

Comment: This restricts alpha to 0..Pi/4 and Pi/2..3Pi/4 (the second interval in your question should have Pi/2 instead of Pi on the left)

Comment: If your conclusion that the common sign of sin(2alpha) and cos(2alpha) implies that tau and sigma_x - sigma_y have the same sign is correct, the premise is indeed faulty. tau and sigma_x - sigma_y are not sign-restricted.

Comment: I have the nagging sense that the authors may actually be correct.  See figure 1.9, if you can access the preview: https://books.google.com/books?id=hJiRDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement in the book has to be viewed through the lens of a particular method of proof.  My original effort was not consistent with that approach.  I now believe I can state the intent of the authors in a more satisfying manner.

Define the vector constant

$$\mathfrak{b}\equiv\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}\right)\\
\tau^{x}{}_{y}
\end{bmatrix}\equiv b\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left[\beta\right]\\
\sin\left[\beta\right]
\end{bmatrix}\equiv b\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[\beta\right],$$

the vector variable

$$\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[2\alpha\right]\equiv\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\\
\sin\left[2\alpha\right]
\end{bmatrix},$$

and the scalar the constant $\left\langle \sigma\right\rangle \equiv\frac{\sigma^{x}+\sigma^{y}}{2}.$ The first normal stress transformation equation (1.9a) is now written

$$\sigma^{\overline{x}}=\left\langle \sigma\right\rangle +\mathfrak{b}\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[2\alpha\right].$$

Setting the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ equal to $0$ produces

$$0=\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[\beta\right]\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[2\alpha+\frac{\pi}{2}\right].$$

Which implies

$$\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[2\alpha\right]=\pm\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[\beta\right].$$

So that

$$b\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\left[2\alpha\right]=\pm\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}\\
2\tau^{x}{}_{y}
\end{bmatrix}=\pm\begin{bmatrix}\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\\
\sin\left[2\alpha\right]
\end{bmatrix},\text{and}$$

$$\tan\left[2\alpha\right]=\frac{\pm2\tau^{x}{}_{y}}{\pm\left(\sigma^{x}-\sigma^{y}\right)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Ref. 1 writes [admittedly somewhat confusingly]:

> [...], and noting that the sine and cosine are either both plus or both minus, [...]

Ref. 1 does *not* say that sine and cosine are either both positive or either both negative in eqs. (1.12a)-(1.12b), which would have been incorrect$^{\dagger}$. Rather Ref. 1 is trying to say [that it follows from eq. (1.12)] that either both the upper $+$ signs in the $\pm$ symbol apply, or both the lower $-$ signs in the $\pm$ symbol apply, but a mixture with one upper $+$ sign and one lower $-$ sign is *not* allowed.

References:

1. Pei Chi Chou & Nicholas J. Pagano, *Elasticity: Tensor, Dyadic, and Engineering Approaches,* 1967; p.9-10.

$^{\dagger}$ The variable $\alpha$ is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Hence the question: **Is the claim that $\sin\left[2\alpha\right]\cos\left[2\alpha\right]\ge0$ valid?**

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: What are the values of $\sin\left[2\alpha\right]$ and $\cos\left[2\alpha\right]$ in the case of maximal normal stress directed along a line forming an angle $\frac{\pi}{4}<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$ with the $X$--axis?  How does that correspond to the claim in the book?

Comment: Your answer may be perfectly correct, but I didn't understand it.  That may well indicate my own inadequacy.  Please don't assume my failure to accept your answer indicates ingratitude on my part.